# TinyMCE GET 404

Tags: django, amazon-s3, tinymce

I installed TinyMCE and it was working fine on the local server. I deploy the site to Heroku and host the static files on Amazon S3 and now TinyMCE is not working. Other static files are served correctly. This is the Heroku log.

```
2020-04-15T07:19:17.547578+00:00 app[web.1]: - [15/Apr/2020:07:19:17 +0000] "GET /static/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3012 "https://...herokuapp.com/.../" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.39 Safari/537.36"
```

This is the folder structure of my site:

```
.
├── Procfile
├── db.sqlite3
├── mysite
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
├── media
│   ├── images
│   └── js
├── requirements.txt
├── runtime.txt
├── static
│   └── readme.txt
├── staticfiles
│   └── readme.txt
└── myapp
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __pycache__
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── forms.py
    ├── migrations
    ├── models.py
    ├── static
        └── myapp
            └── tiny_mce
    ├── templates
    ├── tests.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── views.py
```

This is my URL configs:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'


MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

TINYMCE_JS_URL = os.path.join(STATIC_URL, "tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js")
TINYMCE_JS_ROOT = os.path.join(STATIC_URL, "tiny_mce")

TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'theme': 'advanced',
    'relative_urls': False,
    'theme_advanced_buttons1': 'bold,italic,underline,bullist,numlist,link,unlink,styleselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect',
}
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: In your URL configs, it looks like you are setting up TinyMCE to be in /static/tiny_mce/, but in your folder structure, TinyMCE lives in /static/myapp/tiny_mce

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Do you mind posting your comment as an answer so I can tick it?